# Ruby Silent Installation Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install Ruby in silent mode with the options mentioned below through PowerShell:

```
echo "Installing Ruby 2.0.0"
$ruby_inst_process = Start-Process "C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648-x64.exe" /silent /tasks='assocfiles,modpath' -PassThru -Wait
if ($ruby_inst_process -ne 0) 
{
    echo "Ruby 2.0.0 installation failed"
    exit 0
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/tasks=assocfiles,modpath'.
+ ... t_process = Start-Process "C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or simply using incorrect syntax.

Comment: Pass arguments using `-ArgumentList` parameter.  `$ruby_inst_process = Start-Process "C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648-x64.exe" -ArgumentList "/silent /tasks='assocfiles,modpath'" -PassThru -Wait`

Comment: @RyanBemrose: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your arguments using the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

```
$ruby_inst_process = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648-x64.e‌​xe" -ArgumentList "/silent /tasks='assocfiles,modpath'" -PassThru -Wait
```

To make it a bit easier to understand, use variables to break down the line.

```
$exe = "C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648-x64.e‌​xe"
$args = "/silent /tasks='assocfiles,modpath'"

$ruby_inst_process = Start-Process -FilePath $exe -ArgumentList $args -PassThru -Wait
```

There is also an error in this line: `if ($ruby_inst_process -ne 0)`  The return from `Start-Process -PassThru` is a `Process` object, not a simple number or string.  What you probably want is the `ExitCode` property on this object.

```
if ($ruby_inst_process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    "Ruby 2.0.0 installation failed"
    exit 0
}
```

Comment: It worked and thanks. But getting another error with string type when checking exit value.
`Installing Ruby 2.0.0
Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At D:\VBox Shared\mcollective_install.ps1:5 char:2
+     Write-Host "$ruby_inst_process"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromAnyTypeToString

Ruby 2.0.0 installation failed`

Comment: Two nits: 1) Powershell behaves similarly to JavaScript's semicolon insertion, so always put opening curly braces on the same line as your `if`, not the next line.  2) You don't need to concatenate strings with `+` to print variables in PS.  Just insert it into the string like`"the third value of $setname is $($values[2])`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how powershell interprets whitespace, it is trying to pass `/tasks=assocfiles,modpath` as an argument to start-process rather than to the ruby installer.  There are two fixes to this problem.  The first is to provide an `-argumentlist` parameter like below

```
 Start-Process "C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648-x64.exe" -argumentlist @("/silent","/tasks='assocfiles,modpath'") -PassThru -Wait
```

or by using `Invoke-Expression` instead of `Start-Process`, this executes an entire string as a single command

```
Invoke-Expression ""C:\Users\guest_new\Downloads\rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p648-x64.exe" /silent /tasks='assocfiles,modpath'"
```

Note you probably need to play with the quote's in order to get the order right on the `Invoke-Expression`